# modify labelitem only in alertblock

Tags: beamer, itemize

I would like to change the bullet, but only within a specified block (alertblock). How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{block}{Block}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{alertblock}{Alertblock}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Another test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{alertblock}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item Yet another test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginEnvironment{alertblock}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{x}  
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
  \begin{block}{Block}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \begin{alertblock}{Alertblock}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Another test
    \end{itemize}
  \end{alertblock}

  \begin{itemize}
  \item Yet another test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]